# Getting error trying to pass request options

Tags: angular

I have a service like this:

```
   import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import { Usuario } from "../_models/usuarios";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { User } from "../_models/user.model";


 private serviceUrl = "apiUrl";
  headers = new Headers({
    Authorization:
      "Bearer " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")).token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  });
  options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

constructor(private http: Http, private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getUser(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<User[]>(this.serviceUrl);
  }
```

Problem is when I try to send options to get method like:

```
getUser(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<User[]>(this.serviceUrl, this.options);
  }
```

It returns:

> message: 'Argument of type 'RequestOptions' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]:
>   string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.   Types of
>   property 'headers' are incompatible.
>       Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
>         Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
>           Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.'

I try to change it using http instead httpClient like:

```
 return this.http.get<User[]>(this.serviceUrl, this.options);
```

But now I get

> message: 'Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HttpClient` it is from `@angular/common/http` something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Usuario } from "../_models/usuarios";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { User } from "../_models/user.model";

@Injectable()
export class UserService{
private serviceUrl = "apiUrl";
  headers = new HttpHeaders({
    Authorization: "Bearer " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")).token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  });

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getUser(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<User[]>(this.serviceUrl, { 'headers': this.headers});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use httpClient, you should

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")).token
    })
}

...

getUser(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<User[]>(this.serviceUrl,httpOptions);
}
```